# TCPDF html render not indented

Tags: html, indentation, tcpdf

I'm trying to display data with TCPDF from my DB which were specifically indented.

I use a writeHTMLCell to do so.

e.g. :

"This should be indented as so :
      - First bullet
      - Second one
Then the end of the example."

But of course, it render the text on a single line.

Does anyone know how i can render the text properly ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Please provide an example of the html content you are trying to display.

Comment: It's just plain text. No tags or anything. In the db it's correctly formatted, but render on a single line in the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTML preformatted text requires that you use [`<pre>`](https://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements/pre). Here is an example:

```html
This should be indented as so:
  - First bullet
  - Second one
Then the end of the example.

<pre>
This should be indented as so:
  - First bullet
  - Second one
Then the end of the example.
</pre>
```

Using `<pre>` tags with the preformatted text block should achieve the result you are looking for. Preformatted text defaults to a monospaced font and can be changed with `$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont()`. Here is an example with and without `<pre>`:

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();

$text_sample = 'This should be indented as so:
    - First bullet
    - Second one
Then the end of the example.';

$y = $pdf->getY();
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 14, '', true);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 92, 92);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(190, '', '', $y, $text_sample, 1, 0, 1, true, 'J', true);
$pdf->SetTextColor(53,183,41);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(190, '', '', $y+20, '<pre>'.$text_sample.'</pre>', 1, 1, 1, true, 'J', true);

$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');
```

The PDF will contain the following cells:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks you very much !